# How does a JTable handle a null value?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When `JTable` invokes `getValueAt()` and that method return a `null` value, does it blow up? Or does it just show an empty string ""?

I ask because I've been returning an `""` as `null`, but I'm trying to be more explicit with my `getClass()` method and "" can clash with nonstring types.

Comment: ...it wouldn't hurt to experiment for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends how the value is rendered. It is up to a particular renderer to draw the actual data. See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information.

For example, `DefaultTableCellRenderer` that extends `JLabel` treats `null` like this:

```
protected void setValue(Object value) {
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
}
```

So, `null` is interpreted as an empty string.